# Creating a Blank image based on the dimensions from another pictures

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image with this dimension (1280 x 960). To create a Blank image with this dimension, I use this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np    
blank_image2 = 255 * np.ones(shape=[960, 1280, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Is it possible to create a blank image based on the dimension of another `image`? Something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np    
blank_image2 = 255 * np.ones(shape=image, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but `np.zeros_like()` gets you a blank image with tbe right shape and `dtype`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the shape of the image object:

```
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
h, w, c = image.shape
blank_image2 = 255 * np.ones(shape=(h, w, c), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Amin is correct, I'm just sharing an alternative using 'ones_like' - similar to Mark's suggestion:

```
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
blank_image = 255 * np.ones_like(image , dtype = np.uint8)
```